# Why is Thunderbird not updated as frequently and quickly as Firefox in Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, 19.10, thunderbird

I am a regular user of Firefox and Thunderbird. I have been using solely Ubuntu for more than a year. An interesting thing I noticed is that while Firefox is updated as quickly as possible (with a lag of at most several days) in Ubuntu repositories, the same is not true for Thunderbird.

1. The latest official version for Firefox is 74.0; it was released just two days ago and Ubuntu just updated it today.
2. The latest official version for Thunderbird is 68.5.0 which was released more than a month ago; while Ubuntu repositories still have not updated Thunderbird since version 68.4.1, which was released more than two months ago:

> Version 68.4.1, first offered to channel users on January 9, 2020
>
> Version 68.4.2, first offered to channel users on January 24, 2020
>
> Version 68.5.0, first offered to channel users on February 11, 2020

Note: I am only interested about the **supported** PPAs and I am not currently using the "snap store" for these software. However, checking the snap store will reveal that the same (68.4.1) Thunderbird version is provided there too.

Comment: More info required: is firefox a snap? Is thunderbird a snap? And you are aware  we use a 6 month cycle for software? ( and that 6 month cycle is well inside your 2 months ;) ) do you have issues with snap installs? If not, install tbird using snap.

Comment: There's a ppa here: https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=eoan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New upstream versions are NOT pushed to Ubuntu repositories after release (except Web Browsers and a couple other critical exceptions, which are pushed). E-mail clients are not one of those exceptions.

The normal Security Team process is that vulnerabilities get tracked and patched, then a new, safe package is released in the security pocket.

- The version number gets a *minor* bump, since this is not a new upstream release. Example: Thunderbird 68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.**1** gets bumped to 68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.**2**. It's just as *safe* as 68.5. All the same (declared) vulns are addressed.

The exception for web browsers is that the newest upstream release is always pushed to all releases of Ubuntu by the Security Team. There are several reasons for this: Browsers are more widely and more intensively used, are more complex, and have more interaction with other hardware on your system.

- This is a new upstream release, so the major version number gets bumped. Example: Firefox **72**.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 gets bumped to **74**.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1

In the specific example of Thunderbird: 68.4.2 won't be pushed to Ubuntu 19.10 users, since 19.10 has already been released. However, all the vulnerabilities fixed in 68.4.2 were backported to 68.4.1 by the Ubuntu Security Team. Your patched 68.4.1 is safe. Thunderbird 68.5 is in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Although I accepted your answer, this does not explain the reason we are still in 68.4.1, while 68.4.2 was released more than 1.5 months ago.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli edited to address your comment.

Comment: yes it does; We use a 6 month cycle.